# Resume SFTP download after connection fails (pysftp / paramiko)

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'm trying to build a simple SFTP client using pysftp / paramiko.

How can I resume a transfer if it gets interrupted, e.g. if the connection fails? Is there a way to restart the transfer, find that the file already exists then begin transferring more data from the point where it got broken off?

I can't find any clear information on this in the documentation to either module. Is there nothing similar to the `reget` command in OpenSSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Paramiko nor pysftp support transfer resume. But if you take a look at the [`SFTPClient.get` implementation](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/2.7.2/paramiko/sftp_client.py#L785), it should be easy to implement the resume. The following should do:

```
if os.path.isfile(localpath):
    localsize = os.stat(localpath)
else
    localsize = 0
remotesize = sftp.stat(remotepath).st_size
if localsize < remotesize:
    with open(localpath, "ab") as fl,
         sftp.open(remotepath, "rb") as fr:
        if localsize > 0:
            fr.seek(localsize)
        fr.prefetch(remotesize)
        sftp._transfer_with_callback(
            reader=fr, writer=fl, file_size=remotesize, callback=None)
```